# Detecting spikes and drops in a long list of integers C#

Tags: c#, list, intervals

Hi there I'm trying to write a method that reads every number in a list and detects where it spikes and drops. This is what I have so far:

I basically figure if I loop through the list, loop through it again to get the next number in the list, then detecting if it's more or less. If it's more it'll save to one list, vice versa.

What I want this method to do is determine where there's a spike of 100 or more, save the point that it does this (which is 'counter') and also save the points where the numbers drop.

This so far notices only a drop and it will save every number in the list until it spikes again and once it has spiked it shows no numbers, until it drops again and so on.

I've put 'check' and 'check2' to try and counteract it saving every number after it notices a drop and only save it once but no luck.

Any ideas?

```
public void intervalDetection()
{
    //Counter is the point in the list
    int counter = 0;
    int spike = 0;
    int drop = 0;

    //Loop through power list
    for (int i = 0; i < powerList.Count(); i++)
    {
        counter++;               
        int firstNumber = powerList[i]; 

        //Loop again to get the number after??
        for (int j = 1; j < 2; j++)
        {                  
            //Detect Spike
            spike = firstNumber + 100;
            drop = firstNumber - 100;                       

                if (powerList[j] > spike)
                {
                    if (check2 == false)
                    {
                        intervalStartList.Add(counter);
                        check2 = true;
                        check = false;
                    }
                }
                //Detect Drop
                else if (powerList[j] < drop)
                {
                    if (check == false)
                    {
                        intervalEndList.Add(counter);
                        check = true;
                        check2 = false;
                    }
                }

        }
```

Comment: Your index for 'j' I think is wrong.  It is always index 1.

Answer (score 2):

1. Create integer "average"
2. Loop through List/Array and add each value to average
3. Divide average by the count of the List/Array
4. Loop through List/Array and check deviation to the average integer
5. derp

Code example:

```
public class DSDetector {
   public static List<int>[] getDropsnSpikes(List<int> values, int deviation) {
      List<int> drops = new List<int>();
      List<int> spikes = new List<int>();
      int average = 0;
      foreach (int val in values) {
         average += val;
      }
      average = average/values.Count;
      foreach (int val in values) {
         if (val < average - deviation) {
            drops.add(val);
         }
         if (val > average + deviation) {
            spikes.add(val);
         }
      }
      //derp.
      return new List<int>{drops, spikes};
   }
}
```

not tested but I think it works. Just try it.

Comment: This works yes, but it's detecting loads of spike values and loads of drop values. I'm trying to get it so it will take the value where it drops and only that value, until it spikes, then it will take the value where it spikes

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean saying "peaks" and "drops"?
Let's say you have following list of integers

112, 111, 113, 250, 112, 111, 1, 113

In this case value 250 is peak and 1 drop relative to average value and you can get it using Kai_Jan_57 answer.

But also 250 is peak to previous value 113 and 112 is drop for 250. 
If you want to find local peaks and drops you can check each value relative to previous and next: find average as avg=(val[i-1]+val[i+1])/2 and check if val[i]>avg + 100 (peak) or val[i]